# Determine if any combinations of doubles from a set sum to target value

Tags: algorithm, set

I have a problem at work that has me a little stumped.  I need to validate that a given dose of a medication can be constructed from any combination of pill dose sizes.

For example

```
dose = 400.0
sizes= [15.0, 30.0, 45.0]
```

400 can not be created by any sum of those values (at least I think thats true).  However if the variables were changed to:

```
dose = 400.0 
sizes = [10.0, 15.0, 30.0]
```

I would expect a result of true because 10x40 = 400.  Or if this was the senario:

```
dose = 405.0
sizes = [2.5, 15.0, 30.0, 100.0]
```

I would also expect a true result becuase 4x100 + 2X2.5 = 405.

How would you approach writing this algorithm?  It seems to be related to a [Subset Sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem) algorithm, but in my case I want to allow multiple occurrences of any set item to be part of the solution.

Comment: Your title says "doubles", but all the examples are integers. There might be some algorithms that work well for integer inputs but not at all for floating-point inputs.

Comment: @aschepler good point, I updated my question

Comment: Can you transform the doubles into integers by multiplying by an appropriate factor? If so, then dynamic programming can solve the integer problem

Comment: Chicken McNugget Theorem solves this problem for integers in constant time, if you have 2 sizes: https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Chicken_McNugget_Theorem

Comment: If your spec actually says "double", question its validity.

Comment: No spec here, but I will have to handle floating point values in both dose size and pill size.

Comment: "I will have to handle floating point values" There is no such thing as floating point value outside of a computer program. Weights and dosages are not floating point values. They are *approximate* real numbers. You need to decide how you handle computations with imprecise numbers. [You can't naively rely on floating point arithmetic](https://ideone.com/nuCaDP).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following `Java` implementation solves your problem for double values.

Note - [Java is known for its inaccuracy](http://www.drdobbs.com/jvm/javas-floating-point-imprecision/240168744) when handling double/float based arithmetics. However, for lower precisions, this solution should suffice. Naturally, this algorithm can be implemented in coding languages which do not suffer as much from the precision problem, such as C++.
Updated the algorithm with a tolerance threshold check. This means finer precision is now also handled. Thanks to [aschepler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/459640/aschepler) for pointing out a problematic precision use case.

Two algorithms have been implemented (based on the classical [coin change problem](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamic-programming-set-7-coin-change/)) using [an online java compiler](https://www.jdoodle.com/online-java-compiler):

- one which simply returns a boolean indicating if there is a subset which provides the given sum
- an extension of the first algorithm with a listing of the values used from the subset

The code is below:

```java
import java.util.*;

    public class MyClass {
        public static void main(String args[]) {

        double set[] = {2.5, 15.0, 30.0, 100.0};
        double sum = 405.0;
        int n = set.length;
        if (count(set, n, sum))
            System.out.println("Found a subset with given sum");
        else
            System.out.println("No subset with given sum");
            
        List<Double> listing = new ArrayList<Double>();
        if (countList(set, n, sum,listing))
            System.out.println("Found a subset with given sum: " + listing);
        else
            System.out.println("No subset with  given sum");
    }
    
    public static boolean count( double S[], int m, double n)
    {
        // If n is near 0 then there is 1 solution 
        // (do not include any coin)
        if (n >= -0.00001 && n <= 0.00001)
            return true;
         
        // If n is less than 0 then no 
        // solution exists
        if (n < 0)
            return false;
     
        // If there are no coins and n 
        // is greater than 0, then no
        // solution exist
        if (m <=0 && n > 0)
            return false;
     
        // count is true if one of the solutions (i) including S[m-1] (ii) excluding S[m-1] is true
        return count( S, m - 1, n ) ||
               count( S, m, n-S[m-1] );
    }
    public static boolean countList( double S[], int m, double n, List<Double> listing)
    {
        // If n is near 0 then there is 1 solution 
        // (do not include any coin)
        if (n >= -0.00001 && n <= 0.00001)
            return true;
         
        // If n is less than 0 then no 
        // solution exists
        if (n < 0)
            return false;
     
        // If there are no coins and n 
        // is greater than 0, then no
        // solution exist
        if (m <=0 && n > 0)
            return false;
     
        // count is true if one of the solutions (i) including S[m-1] (ii) excluding S[m-1] is true
        List<Double> with = new ArrayList<>();
        with.add(S[m-1]);
        List<Double> without = new ArrayList<>();
        boolean withResult = countList( S, m, n-S[m-1], with );
        boolean withoutResult = countList( S, m - 1, n, without );
        if(withResult) {
            listing.addAll(with);
        }
        else if (withoutResult) {
            listing.addAll(without);
        }
        return withResult || withoutResult;
    }
}
```

And the output:

```
Found a subset with given sum
Found a subset with given sum: [100.0, 100.0, 100.0, 100.0, 2.5, 2.5]
```

And here is a more challenging input:

```
double set[] = {2.5, 15.0, 30.0, 100.0, 0.2, 0.3};
double sum = 165.9;
Found a subset with given sum
Found a subset with given sum: [0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 100.0, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5]
```

And also:

```
double set[] = {0.2, 0.3, 2.5, 15.0, 30.0, 100.0};
double sum = 148.6;
Found a subset with given sum
Found a subset with given sum: [100.0, 30.0, 15.0, 2.5, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.2]
```

Following precision fix:

```
double set[] = {0.05, 0.012, 0.008};
double sum = 0.1;
Found a subset with given sum
Found a subset with given sum: [0.008, 0.008, 0.008, 0.008, 0.008, 0.008, 0.008, 0.008, 0.008, 0.008, 0.008, 0.012]
```

References:

- [Change-Making Problem definition in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change-making_problem)
- [Coin Change Problem - Review and C++ based solution](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/coin-change/problem)
- [Coin Exchange Problem — Greedy or Dynamic Programming?](https://medium.com/@emailarunkumar/coin-exchange-problem-greedy-or-dynamic-programming-6e5ebe5a30b5)
- [Float and double in Java "inaccurate" result](http://piotrnowicki.com/2011/02/float-and-double-in-java-inaccurate-result/)

Comment: @cobolstinks : Sorry for the relatively late comment-answer. Both algorithms do, indeed, return the first set that they find. You can reorder the set of sizes used as an input in order to get other possible solutions - the algorithm uses the sizes from last to first.

Comment: C++ can also have floating point inaccuracies, this is inevitable in all languages using a fixed size representation of a floating point number.

Comment: @pkpnd : True, that is an inherint problem of using a bit system in order to describe decimal numbers. C/C++ simply handle these inaccuracies a little better then Java, based on my previous experiences.

Comment: @pkpnd : Fair enough. Thank you for your inputs. Which reminds me - your answer is a very nice example of a reduction (in this case specifically from a double input to an integer input problem). Upvoting your answer.

Comment: @RannLifshitz how would you go about tweeking the list method to return all possible combinations that sum to the target?

Comment: @RannLifshitz NM I found a pretty cool library to handle this situation https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26050/Permutations-Combinations-and-Variations-using-C-G. Thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 2):

One standard way to do this is:

1. Represent all your doubles as rationals, so `[2.5, 15.0, 30.0, 100.0]` becomes `[5/2, 15, 30, 100]`
2. Multiply by the LCM of the denominators to obtain integer sizes: `[5, 30, 60, 200]` and dose is `810`
3. Check that your desired dose is a multiple of the GCF of the sizes: yes, `810` is a multiple of `5` (if not, then it clearly can't be made)
4. Divide by the GCF of the sizes: `[1, 6, 12, 40]` with dose `162`
5. Apply the standard dynamic programming solution to the "[coin change problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change-making_problem)". There are many resources online for this, such as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32403244/coin-change-algorithm-with-dynamic-programming).